# Qual módulos utilizar para realizar parsing de dados de um arquivo em Python?

Tags: python

Tenho uma lista de endereços de repositórios *git* classificados de acordo com o local de sua hospedagem.

```
@GitHub ('@' demonstra que a linha representa um local de hospedagem)
url do repositório a (repositório a ser baixado)
url do repositório b (repositório a ser baixado)
@GoogleCode ('@' demonstra que a linha representa um local de hospedagem)
url do reposiorio c (repositório a ser baixado)
url do repositório d (repositório a ser baixado)
```

Quero separar estes dados (o que é repositório e o que é local de hospedagem), que estarão em um arquivo escrito pelo usuário, da melhor maneira possivel. Minha ideia é utilizar algum módulo como o ConfigParser, que cria pra mim um padrão e previne falhas, espaços desnecessários, etc.

Por enquanto estou fazendo isso na mão com condicionais (caso o primeiro elemento seja '@', defina como local de hospedagem), entretando gostaria de otimizar meu código. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Não diria módulos. Diria que com Python nativo você pode fazer algo ótimo. Você tem algum código já pronto que possa colocar na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o formato for simples assim, sem nenhuma novidade planejada, utilizar alguma biblioteca parser, como o [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), pode dar mais trabalho do que fazer o que você já fez.

Se você tiver algum controle sobre o formato, eu sugeriria primeiramente tentar evitar criar um formato novo e tentar usar algo com um parser já existente, tipo JSON, XML ou YAML (o mais legível desses três).

Comment: Não parei pra pensar enquanto escrevia o código em utilizar um formato JSON. Até que me toquei que os usuários desse meu script são desenvolvedores, e supostamente JSON não será um problema. Estou o utilizando, obrigado pela dica!